# How to get a filename from an ImageView (ANDROID)

Tags: android, imageview, filenames, shuffle

i'd like to get filename of shuffled ImageViews

```
    private List<Drawable> images_;
    images_ = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
    images_.clear();

    images_.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img1));
    images_.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img2));
    images_.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img3));
    images_.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img4));

    Collections.shuffle(images_); 

    ImageView img_1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_1);   
    img_1.setBackgroundDrawable(images_.get(0));
```

How to know what image name was setted in this ImageView (img_1) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setImageResource(resID)` instead of `setBackgroundDrawable`. Now you can get the id of the image as the same resID using the `setId(resID)` Method. To get the image name use the following method.

```
getResources().getResourceName(urImage.getId());


ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
    add(R.drawable.img1);
    add(R.drawable.img2);
    add(R.drawable.img3);
}}
Collections.shuffle(list);
ImageView img_1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.urimageId);   
img_1.setImageResource(list.get(0));
img_1.setTag(list.get(0));
```

Now to get the image name do the following.

```
getResources().getResourceName((Integer)img_1.getTag());
```

Comment: Could you tell me an example about how to do it.. because i have to use images_ as reference and how to get ID from images_.get(0) ?

Comment: To explain my ideia, think that images is fruits like banana, pineapple, strawberry, apple... I know that names, but when it shuffled, i lost reference of images_ and i need to know what frui is on position 0 of this images_.get(0) or images_.get(1)..

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android Developers website the ImageView is inherited from android.view.View. So you can use getResources() to get a Resources object and then use getAssets() to get the AssetManager.

I'm at work so I can't provide example right now. Sorry. I hope this helps though.

Happy coding! :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this to get file name from an ImageView:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
String path = f.getAbsolutePath();                 
iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));
iv.setTag(path);
```

Retrieving the path:

```
String path = (String) iv.getTag();
```

Comment: That is your file path

Comment: Sure, but it is shuffled.. how to know what is the right file path name, i didn't know what image is, because i have 12 ImageView's with 20 image. The images is shuffled and i just get 12 positions (images)..